# CSS3 transition: typewriting html <p> sequentially

Tags: css, opacity, css-transitions

I have got a problem animating an opacity transition on multiple paragraphs to simulate sequential typewriting.
In my page I have three "paragraphs" elements which contains text.
I would like to visualize them sequentially: the first, char by char, then the second, char by char, then the third, char by char.
I noticed the code works only for the n-1 paragraphs... the last is always shown immediately.
So my trick has been to include a "dummy" void as the last paragraph... but I don't like it.
Is there a way to solve the problem in a more elegant way?
My code is as follow:

1. CSS:

   ```
   span.typewrite {
          opacity: 0;
           -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
           -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
           -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
       }
   ```
2. javascript:

   ```
           window.onload = function() {

           var setTypeWrite = function(arr) {
                   var     p, txt, span, t = 0;

               for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
                   p = document.querySelector(arr[a]);
                   txt = p.innerText;
                   p.innerText = "";

                   for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i ++)
                   {
                       span = document.createElement("span");
                       span.className = "typewrite";
                       span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt.substr(i, 1)));
                       span.style["-webkit-transition-delay"] = parseFloat(t * 0.15).toString() + "s";
                       p.appendChild(span);
                       t++;
                   }
               }
           };          

           var startTypeWrite = function(arr) {
               var spans;
               for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
               {
                   spans = document.querySelectorAll(arr[i]);
                   for (var s = 0; s < spans.length; s++) {
                       spans[s].style.opacity = "1";
                   }
               }
           };              

           setTypeWrite(["#text1", "#text2", "#text3", "#dummy"]);                         
           startTypeWrite(["#text1 span.typewrite", "#text2 span.typewrite", "#text3 span.typewrite", "#dummy"]);

       };
   ```
3. HTML body:

   ```
   <p id="text1">text one...</p>
   <p id="text2">text two...</p>
   <p id="text3">text three</p>
   <p id="dummy"></p>
   ```

Comment: Javascript uses zero-based indexing, CSS uses one-based indexing. If you add 1 to the index before passing it to the querySelectorAll() it should work.

Comment: Do you mean in the "startTypeWrite" function? Something like querySelectorAll(arr[i+1])?

Comment: looks like a bug in chrome to me

Comment: I think so; I'm working, so I've not had chance to play with the code, but that's what jumps out at me from looking quickly at what you've posted.

Comment: Could it be a synchronization problem? If I call the "startTypeWrite" function through a setTimeout everything seems to work as expected...

Comment: but I do not like to use setTimeout! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning to the first post, here is a revisited version which works without the dummy paragraph.
It works in Chrome as expected: the "magik" was adding "span.innerText;" after "t++;" in "setTypeWrite" function. I do not know why, but it seems the code needs to read it.

By the way, another question: why it does not work in Firefox?

1. CSS:

   .typewrite {
               opacity: 0;

   ```
           transition-property: opacity;
           transition-duration: 0s;
           transition-timing-function: linear;

           -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
           -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
           -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;

           -moz-transition-property: opacity;
           -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
           -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;

           -o-transition-property: opacity;
           -o-transition-duration: 0s;
           -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
       }
   ```
2. javascript

   window.onload = function() {

   ```
           var setTypeWrite = function(arr) {
                   var p, txt, span, t = 10;

               for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
                   p = document.querySelector(arr[a]);
                   txt = p.textContent;
                   p.textContent = "";

                   for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i ++)
                   {
                       span = document.createElement("span");
                       span.className = "typewrite";
                       span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt.substr(i, 1)));

                       span.style["transition-delay"] = parseFloat(t * 0.2) + "s";
                       span.style["-webkit-transition-delay"] = parseFloat(t * 0.2) + "s";
                       span.style["-moz-transition-delay"] = parseFloat(t * 0.2) + "s";
                       span.style["-o-transition-delay"] = parseFloat(t * 0.2) + "s";

                       p.appendChild(span);
                       t++;
                       span.innerText;
                   }
               }
           };          

           var startTypeWrite = function(arr) {
               var spans;
               for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
               {
                   spans = document.querySelectorAll(arr[i]);
                   for (var s = 0; s < spans.length; s++) {
                       spans[s].style.opacity = "1";
                   }
               }
           };  

           setTypeWrite(["#text1", "#text2", "#text3"]);                         
           startTypeWrite([".typewrite"]);

       };
   ```
3. HTML body:

   text one...

   text two...

   text three...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Considerations.

I updated a part inside "setTypeWrite" function to be Firefox compatible:

```
txt = p.textContent;
p.textContent = "";
```

Then I have added a button to raise the transition:

```
<button id="button">start</button>
document.querySelector("#button").onclick = function() { startTypeWrite(["span.typewrite"]); };
```

Now, in Chrome, clicking on the button starts the animation as expected (without a "dummy" paragraph). It just let me think to a timing error again.

By the way the "typewrited" char by char transition seems not to work in Firefox: document.querySelectorAll(".typewrite") returns "undefined".
Does querySelectorAll works in Firefox?

Comment: Tried in Opera too... apparently the code works only in Chrome.